# UITextFieldDelegate não esconde o teclado

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3, uitextfield

Boa noite, companheiros

estou a ter um pequeno problema com a UITextFieldDelegate.
pretendo que quando o usuario clicar na tecla retorno (Voltar) o teclado desaparece por alguns instantes e volte a textField para escrever algo novamente.
Mas a tecla Retorno e ignorado no ato de execução e o teclado não desaparece. de uma olha no terminal

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var itextField: UITextField!

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {       
        itextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

[image: print de tela]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema de esconder o teclado apenas em delegado a textField na View controller. Clicar na TextField Pressionar control+clique arrastar a teia ate ao atalho da view controller no topo da view controller scene. escolher a opção delegate.

[image: print]

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Tente:

```
itextField.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: Boas, Testei com esta função também funcionou, entretanto o problema não estava no código. Obrigado @Felipe Ricieri

Answer (score 0):

No seu *Main.storyboard*, clique no TextField, vá até o *Attributes Inspector* e procure a opção Keyboard.

Lá tem a opção de fazê-lo sumir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tente a opção **Dismiss interactively**.

Abraços

Comment: No meu não aparece, talvez seja a versão dos nosso xcode a minha é  Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Comment: Perdão, essa opção é para Text View. Testei algumas opções para Text Field, mas não encontrei nada útil!! Desculpe

Comment: Não faz mal. Brother estamos juntos

Answer (score 0):

Para usar funções do delegate você precisa atribuir o delegate do item.

Basta fazer itextField.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não sei como fazer o teclado sumir por alguns instantes, mas usando código abaixo, acho que o teclado irá descer bem rápido e logo voltar.

```
  func dismissKeyboard(){

    view.endEditing(true)
                   }

 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if (textField == self.itextfield) {

        dismissKeyboard()
        itextfield.becomeFirstResponder()

    }else{

    return true

}
}
```

Comment: Aí Renato já consegui resolver a baixo estão os print e da solução.